# Magento get option id for specified attribute set and value

Tags: php, magento

I've been searching for hours now and haven't found any solution to this problem. I need to get the option ID for a configurable product. The current informations I have are the SKU, the attribute set ID and the option label. How can I fetch the option ID using these values?

Many thanks to those who can help me.

** UPDATE **

Here's a sample of the database table eav_attribute_option_value (from wich I'm guessing Magento take the value for the ID)

```
value_id option_id store_id value   
729141   57        0        Rose
729142   57        3        Rose
729143   57        1        Pink
728847   749       0        Pink
728848   749       3        Pink
728849   749       1        Pink
```

I need to get the value ID 57. When the locale is in french, I get the right value. But when I switch to english, I get the ID 749, which is from another attribute set.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fetch the option id you do it easily just like this :

```
     $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1234', 'sku');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    echo $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Red");
}
```

For details you can check this [link](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/09/13/magento-get-product-attribute-select-option-idlabelvalue/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not working in my case. I need to specify an attribute set (which I have the ID). Have a look at my update.

Answer (score 0):

My own query for getting the attribute option id from the database. All you must specify is the attribute name and the value. E.g:

```
SELECT ao.option_id
FROM `eav_attribute_option` AS ao, `eav_attribute_option_value` AS av
WHERE ao.option_id = av.option_id
AND av.value LIKE 'dragon'
AND ao.attribute_id IN
(SELECT attribute_id
 FROM eav_attribute
 WHERE attribute_code
 LIKE 'manufacturer')
```